# CNN loss with multiple outputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have the following model

```
def get_model():
epochs = 100
learning_rate = 0.1
decay_rate = learning_rate / epochs

inp = keras.Input(shape=(64, 101, 1), name="inputs")
x = layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(3, 3), padding="same")(inp)
x = layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(3, 3), padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(150)(x)
x = layers.Dense(150)(x)
out1 = layers.Dense(40000, name="sf_vec")(x)
out2 = layers.Dense(128, name="ls_weights")(x)

model = keras.Model(inp, [out1, out2], name="2_out_model")

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=decay_rate),  # in caso rimettere 0.001
              loss="mean_squared_error")

keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
model.summary()

return model
```

[image]

that is, I want to train my neural network based on the "mix" of the loss from the first output and the loss from the second output.
I train my neural network in this way:

```
model.fit(x_train, [sf_train, ls_filters_train], epochs=10)
```

and during the training ,for example, this is shown:
Epoch 10/10 -> loss: 0.0702 - sf_vec_loss: 0.0666 - ls_weights_loss: 0.0035

I'd like to know if it's a case that the "loss" is nearly the sum between the sf_vec_loss and ls_weights_loss or if keras is actually reasoning in this way.
Also, is the network being trained on the "loss" only?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following the Tensorflow [Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile)...

from the `loss` argument:

> If the model has multiple outputs, you can use a different loss on
> each output by passing a dictionary or a list of losses. The loss
> value that will be minimized by the model will then be the **sum** of all
> individual losses

remember also that you can also weight the loss contributions of different model outputs

from the `loss_weights` argument:

> The loss value that will be minimized by the model will then be the
> **weighted sum** of all individual losses, weighted by the loss_weights coefficients